# Area/Type of triangle python

Tags: python, area

I'm supposed to find a code that asks the user for the base, height, and side of a triangle and then tells the user "This (type) triangle has an area of (area)" and then keeps asking the user for more numbers until they decide to quit. The code I have so far is...

```
again = "y"
while again != "n":

base = int(input("Enter base: "))  
height = int(input("Enter height: "))  
side1 = int(input("Enter side 1:  "))
side2 = int(input("Enter side 2:  "))
side3 = int(input("Enter side 3:  "))
area = (base*height) / 2

certain_type = []
if side1 == side2 == side3:
        print("Equilateral triangle")
    elif side1==side2 or side2==side3 or side1==side3:
        print("isosceles triangle")
    else:
        print("Scalene triangle")


print('This %f of the triangle is %0.2f' %area, certaintype)
```

Comment: What's your **specific** question?

Comment: Well done, so a few comments...

1) indentation throws it off because the entire code should be under the while loop.

Comment: a typo here : certaintype and certain_type , this list remains empty. What do you want to add in it ?

Answer (score -1):

Well done, so a few comments...

(1) indentation throws it off because the entire code should be under the while loop, so that your entire game will repeat itself after every triangle

(2) Instead of directly printing the "isosceles", "scalene" etc, "certaintype" ...you can store the value (eg scalene) under the certaintype variable using `certaintype='scalene'`. That way, you can print the type of triangle in your sentence later.

(3) The final print should also be under the while loop as you want to tell your users the answer after every triangle information entry.

(4) The syntax for string interpolation is %s for string variables like `certaintype` while the syntax for number/decimals is %d for number variables like `area`. Check out how I rewrote the final print line.

Somethig like this should work:

```
while again != "n":

    base = int(input("Enter base: "))
    height = int(input("Enter height: "))
    side1 = int(input("Enter side 1:  "))
    side2 = int(input("Enter side 2:  "))
    side3 = int(input("Enter side 3:  "))
    area = (base*height) / 2

    certain_type = []
    if side1 == side2 == side3:
        certaintype = "Equilateral triangle"
    elif side1==side2 or side2==side3 or side1==side3:
        certaintype = "isosceles triangle"
    else:
        certaintype = "Scalene triangle"


    print('This %d of the triangle is %s' % (certaintype, area) )
```

Comment: I downvoted your question. What you seem to have done is a code review. But code reviews are not a service we offer here, they can be request at our sibling site [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @KlausD. This is an answer, not a question.

Comment: That's true. But that little mistake does not invalidate the message.